# urllib or json memory leak python 3

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, memory-leaks, urllib

I would like to fetch and use data from url and then repeat a loop.
When I ran code my operation memory usage (MacOS) increase with every loop. How can I prevent that?

Thank You in advance!

```
import urllib.request, json 
import time
import resource
import gc
import contextlib

def bb():
    try:        
        with contextlib.closing(urllib.request.urlopen("https://bitbay.net/API/Public/ETHPLN/ticker.json")) as url:
        data = json.loads(url.read().decode())

        ## do something with data

        del data
        gc.collect()

    except urllib.error.HTTPError as err:
        pass


def resident_memory() -> int:
    return resource.getrusage(resource.RUSAGE_SELF).ru_maxrss


x = 0
while x == 0:
    bb()
    print('Mem usage:', resident_memory())
    time.sleep(1)
```

Comment: I did some experiments, the culprit is not `json` nor underlying socket, but within `urllib`, need more time to find out.

Comment: Thank You. I hope that You will resolve it!

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same problem with Python 3.7.4. I ended up switching to urllib3 (https://urllib3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) and the problem instantly went away. Also, I put my HTTP PoolManager outside of the scope of the loop.